# Twitter::Error::Forbidden - Unable to verify your credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, twitter-gem

I'm using devise + omniauth and I can connect to twitter api correctly.

But when I try to use twitter gem, I have the following error in console :

"Twitter::Error::Forbidden - Unable to verify your credentials"

I have installed the gem and created an initializer at config/initializers/twitter.rb

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = PKe41...
    config.consumer_secret = qETY.....
end
```

And I'm trying into a controller :

```
def twitter
    @twitter_home_timeline = Twitter.home_timeline
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer... Keys in the initializer must be set with quotation marks :

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = 'PKe41...'
    config.consumer_secret = 'qETY.....'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add oauth token and secret
If you don't, you just give two credentials of an account.
It can't find the correct app used for these credentials.

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end
```

Comment: it works without oauth token and secret - that implies less access to user's data.thanks anyway !