# Can't connect to Twitter API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter, environment-variables, bots

I am creating a twitter bot, deployed on heroku, that should tweet random combinations of words at regular intervals.  I set my ENV variables in heroku using

```
$ heroku config:set CONSUMER_KEY=xxxx CONSUMER_SECRET=xxxx
```

(etc. for all of the variables)
When I try to run the bot locally by typing in the terminal

```
rails runner app/models/twitter_bot.rb
```

I get the below error

```
in `on_complete': Unable to verify your credentials    (Twitter::Error::Forbidden)
```

I used heroku config to double-check that none of the access tokens or keys are incorrectly spelled.  The asker of this similar question [Twitter::Error::Forbidden - Unable to verify your credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719358/twittererrorforbidden-unable-to-verify-your-credentials) had an issue with quotation marks, but I used quotation marks in the twitter_bot.rb file when I created the client - see below:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|  
  config.consumer_key = ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"]  
  config.consumer_secret = ENV["CONSUMER_SECRET"]  
  config.access_token = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"]  
  config.access_token_secret = ENV["ACCESS_SECRET"]  
end
```

Any idea why twitter can't verify my credentials?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`heroku config:set` sets the environmental variables on the heroku environment, not your local environment. Use `export CONSUMER_KEY=xxxx` to set environmental variables on your local machine.